# Does git have an "I am an idiot" switch to prevent push -f without a branch?

Tags: git

I just did a

```
git push -f
```

without including the branch I intended to push and git just blasted in everything to my repo. Fortunately we could piece together the old repo without to much trouble but it would be nice if I could change a setting in git to prevent -f all or make it so I have to do it explicitly.

Anyone aware of a setting I can change for this?

Comment: The funny thing is, `git` already requires a special flag (`-f`) if you want to hurt yourself.  Some sort of "I-know-said-force-but-please-don't-believe-me" setting seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: I don't think there's an option to do this, unless you compile your own version of git and add a prompt (or even remove the option). I think this falls in the same category as running `rm -rf` in *nix, an not realizing that you're running it as root on `/`. I quote the last sentence from the documentation **use it with care**. The only consolation I can give is that all devs have destroyed something in their careers (I have a predilection for databases).

Comment: Doesn't address your issue but along the same lines some of my colleagues prefer using Easy Git (http://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/) which adds a layer on top of porcelain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a `pre-receive`  hook on the remote repo, that can prevent force push. You can also ensure that force push can only be done if explicitly specifying a particular branch.

You can also setup your local repository to change the default behaviour of the `git push` so that it will push only the current branch:

> For example, to default to pushing only the current branch to origin
>   use git config remote.origin.push HEAD. Any valid  (like the
>   ones in the examples below) can be configured as the default for git
>   push origin.

Comment: any luck with this and github?

Comment: @matthewdaniel -for github you will have to go with the second approach I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The git **push.default** option is exactly what you are looking for.
From git documentation at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config:

> ### push.default
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what you want. Possible values are:
>
> - *nothing* - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
> - *current* - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - *upstream* - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
> - *simple* - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch's name is different from the local one.
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.
>   This mode will become the default in Git 2.0.
> - *matching* - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed there).
>   To use this mode effectively, you have to make sure all the branches you would push out are ready to be pushed out before running git push, as the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the branches in one go. If you usually finish work on only one branch and push out the result, while other branches are unfinished, this mode is not for you. Also this mode is not suitable for pushing into a shared central repository, as other people may add new branches there, or update the tip of existing branches outside your control.
>   This is currently the default, but Git 2.0 will change the default to simple.

In your situation, you might want to use **git config --global push.default nothing** to make sure you never push anything without specifying a refspec explicitely.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a setting for this. But I do agree that the mistake could be NOT including the branch name and force all to overwrite. If Git had a the ability, disable -f if no branch is specified. Maybe I'll submit a patch..

Comment: How can you disable -f if no branch is specified? This is what I am looking for.

Comment: I should have been clearer. Git should have a setting such as this.

Comment: +1 for considering submitting a patch. Your idea may need a `-f -f` (double force) for the `no branch == current branch` case, which is the first example in the man page's Examples section, for when folk 'really mean it'.